# IF statement does not recognize OR expression

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, osx-lion

I'm breaking my head, with this. I do not understand why the below IF statement is not working

```
renameOption="-rs"
if [[ $# -eq 4 ]]; then
if [[ $renameOption != "-rs" ]] || [[ $renameOption != "-rb" ]]; then
    echo -e "\tArgument three needs to be '-rs' or '-rb'"
    echo -e "\tNow exiting script"
    exit
fi
flag=1
echo "Good to go"
fi
```

I know the syntax is right, but what I noticed is that the system does not recognize the OR `||` expression in the second IF. When using a single expression, it works fine, But I need to compare with two expressions, therefore the OR `||`.

I'm running OSX Lion 10.7.4

Comment: for your error message to make sense you should use "&&" operator, not "||", and take it into "[[ ]]" block, like "[[ a && b ]]"

Comment: Thanks, was a little confused. `&&` is the right operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it even make sense? `$renameOption` is always not equal to either of those two. You probably wanted `&&`.

Comment: ah menso, that is right, I guess I'm frustrated that I'm not thinking right...I need a coffee break :)  ... thanks